# The best way to search millions of fuzzy hashes

Tags: lucene, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I have the [spamsum](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net) composite hashes for about ten million files in a database table and I would like to find the files that are reasonably similar to each other. Spamsum hashes are composed of two CTPH hashes of maximum 64 bytes and they look like this:

```
384:w2mhnFnJF47jDnunEk3SlbJJ+SGfOypAYJwsn3gdqymefD4kkAGxqCfOTPi0ND:wemfOGxqCfOTPi0ND
```

They can be broken down into three sections (split the string on the colons):

1. Block size: `384` in the hash above
2. First signature: `w2mhnFnJF47jDnunEk3SlbJJ+SGfOypAYJwsn3gdqymefD4kkAGxqCfOTPi0ND`
3. Second signature: `wemfOGxqCfOTPi0ND`

Block size refers to the block size for the first signature, and the block size for the second signature is twice that of the first signature (here: 384 x 2 = 768). Each file has one of these composite hashes, which means each file has two signatures with different block sizes.

The spamsum signatures can be compared only if their block sizes correspond. That is to say that the composite hash above can be compared to any other composite hash that contains a signature with a block size of 384 or 768. The similarity of signature strings for hashes with similar block size can be takes as a measure of similarity between the files represented by the hashes.

So if we have:

- `file1.blk2 = 768`
- `file1.sig2 = wemfOGxqCfOTPi0ND`
- `file2.blk1 = 768`
- `file2.sig1 = LsmfOGxqCfOTPi0ND`

We can get a sense of the degree of similarity of the two files by calculating some weighted edit distance (like Levenshtein distance) for the two signatures. Here the two files seem to be pretty similar.

```
leven_dist(file1.sig2, file2.sig1) = 2
```

One can also calculate a normalized similarity score between two hashes (see the details [here](http://dfrws.org/2006/proceedings/12-Kornblum.pdf)).

I would like to find any two files that are more than 70% similar based on these hashes, and I have a strong preference for using the available software packages (or APIs/SDKs), although I am not afraid of coding my way through the problem.

I have tried breaking the hashes down and indexing them using Lucene (4.7.0), but the search seems to be slow and tedious. Here is an example of the Lucene queries I have tried (for each single signature -- twice per hash and using the case-sensitive KeywordAnalyzer):

```
(blk1:768 AND sig1:wemfOGxqCfOTPi0ND~0.7) OR (blk2:768 AND sig2:wemfOGxqCfOTPi0ND~0.7)
```

It seems that Lucene's [incredibly fast Levenshtein automata](http://java.dzone.com/news/lucenes-fuzzyquery-100-times) does not accept edit distance limits above 2 (I need it to support up to 0.7 x 64 ≃ 19) and that its normal editing distance algorithm is not optimized for long search terms ([the brute force method used does not cut off calculation once the distance limit is reached](http://wenda.io/questions/1104260/is-lucene-fuzzy-search-lazy.html).) That said, it may be that my query is not optimized for what I want to do, so don't hesitate to correct me on that.

I am wondering whether I can accomplish what I need using any of the algorithms offered by Lucene, instead of directly calculating the editing distance. I have heard that BK-trees are the best way to index for such searches, but I don't know of the available implementations of the algorithm (Does Lucene use those at all?). I have also heard that a probable solution is to narrow down the search list using n-gram methods but I am not sure how that compares to editing distance calculation in terms of inclusiveness and speed (I am pretty sure Lucene supports that one). And by the way, is there a way to have Lucene run a term search in the parallel mode?

Given that I am using Lucene only to pre-match the hashes and that I calculate the real similarity score using the appropriate algorithm later, I just need a method that is at least as inclusive as Levenshtein distance used in similarity score calculation -- that is, I don't want the pre-matching method to exclude hashes that would be flagged as matches by the scoring algorithm.

Any help/theory/reference/code or clue to start with is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a definitive answer to the question, but I have tried a number of methods ever since. I am assuming the hashes are saved in a database, but the suggestions remain valid for in-memory data structures as well.

1. Save all signatures (2 per hash) along with their corresponding block sizes in a separate child table. Since only signatures of the same size can be compared with each other, you can filter the table by block size before starting to compare the signatures.
2. Reduce all the repetitive sequences of more than three characters to three characters ('bbbbb' -> 'bbb'). Spamsum's comparison algorithm does this automatically.
3. Spamsum uses a rolling window of 7 to compare signatures, and won't compare any two signatures that do not have a 7-character overlap after eliminating excessive repetitions. If you are using a database that support lists/arrays as fields, create a field with a list of all possible 7-character sequences extracted from each signature. Then create the fastest exact match index you have access to on this field. Before trying to find the distance of two signatures, first try to do exact matches over this field (any seven-gram in common?).
4. The last step I am experimenting with is to save signatures and their seven-grams as the two modes of a bipartite graph, projecting the graph into single mode (composed of hashes only), and then calculating Levenshtein distance only on adjacent nodes with similar block sizes.

The above steps do a good pre-matching and substantially reduce the number of signatures each signature has to be compared with. It is only after these that the the modified Levenshtein/Damreau distance has to be calculated.